# How to use CSS Paint API with React

Tags: css, reactjs, paint, houdini

I'm trying to set the most basic example of React with the CSS Paint API.

I have no compiling errors and yet the example doesn't show.

Inside `index.html`:

```
<script>
CSS.paintWorklet.addModule('%PUBLIC_URL%/paintWorklet.js');
</script>
```

`public/paintWorklet.js`:

```
class Shape {
  paint(ctx, geom, properties) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

registerPaint('pattern', Shape);
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const TestDiv = () => {  
  return(
    <div className='TestDiv'>
      <h1>I am a TestDiv</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestDiv />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`App.css`:

```
.TestDiv {
  background: paint(pattern);
}
```

So far I have tried to move the worklet inside src, having it inside a useEffect and still no luck.

Although this snippet inside `index.html` works.

```
 <style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: paint(pattern);
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue is:

- Your `TestDiv` has a width and height based on the content.
- The circle you painted is out of the `TestDiv` dimensions, so you would not see the circle.

Solutions:

- Make the `TestDiv` bigger or
- Make the `circle` smaller to fit into the div

[image]

See [demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wizardly-yalow-jfvmk3?file=%2Fpublic%2FpaintWorklet.js&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00063j6ltug0mmm3%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00023j6la4djkq5f%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00033j6lx40cg7fp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00053j6lchs2pt52%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt2ng87o00023j6la4djkq5f%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00023j6la4djkq5f%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltihsyg700023j6jc97ekjp6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252FpaintWorklet.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltihsyg700023j6jc97ekjp6%2522%257D%252C%2522clt2ng87o00053j6lchs2pt52%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00043j6lujtmv0rx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00053j6lchs2pt52%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00043j6lujtmv0rx%2522%257D%252C%2522clt2ng87o00033j6lx40cg7fp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt2ng87o00033j6lx40cg7fp%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)